# Packet forwarding in *nix

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

I am trying to write a python application which does the following:

1. receive packet(say pkt1) from say eth0 from network a.b.c.d
2. parse/process the packet (prspkt1)  check the dstip(q.w.e.r) in
3. routing table and forward the packet through say a different
   interface eth1

I am trying to evaluate different options of achieving step 3

1.using loopback interfaces, Can I send the packet(prspkt1) to loopback interface and let kernel IP module perform step 3 ?

I understand that sending packets to loopback interfaces , puts the packet on the Kernel IP module, but I am unsure if the Kernel would read/process packets from a loopback interface.

Another approach what I have been considering is ,reading the routing table, establishing a socket session to the outgoing interface eth1 and send the packet (prspkt1) through the interface without using loopback interfaces.

Comment: Do you want to modify the packet or merely inspect it? I ask because the kernel already does all of the steps mentioned.

Comment: I understand kernel does that 'thinking' part but I am running an application which partially processes the packets, I am trying to rewrite this functionality which can process the packets and send it to a different interface. I want to make use of the kernel's IP module for routing, but not sure how I can go about making it happen, hence the usage of loopbacks. Can I redirect the packet to loopback interface ? will kernel consider it as a valid packet? As of now, the app just processes the packet and sends it back on eth0 .

Comment: @durga 2 options come to mind initially.  You can open raw sockets and handle the packets directly or use a TAP/TUN interface.  If you want to do real-time packet handling in userspace, there will be very measurable performance penalty however.

Comment: @tMC : thankyou. I am currently attempting to reconstruct a new packet based on the old packet and use scapy to send the packets across without having to deal with unix internals. If that doesnot work, I will restore to creating raw sockets to destination instead of sending packets to loopback IP..